# Graph API bug? /{group-id}/feed endpoint gives inconsistent results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

#### tl;dr getting a group's feed returns inconsistent #s of posts

This apparent bug seems to affect both v1.0 and v2.0 of the Facebook Graph API.

I am an admin of a closed Facebook group with ~1800 posts. I would like to return all of the posts in that group.

To do this, I am calling [/{group-id}/feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/group/feed) and following the URL in `paging.next`. This does in fact return posts, but the results are inconsistent, and usually returns ~150 less posts than are actually in the group (I have independently verified and double-checked this #) .

A base call of `/{group-id}/feed`, when all `paging.next` links are followed, yields **1652** posts.

A base call of `/{group-id}/feed?limit=10`, when all `paging.next` links are followed, yields **1606** posts.

A base call of `/{group-id}/feed?limit=50`, when all `paging.next` links are followed, yields **1687** posts.

Of note, each of the above cases is **internally consistent**. (e.g. the `limit=10` call *always* returns the same (incorrect) number of posts.)

I have been scouring Google and SO trying to troubleshoot. Some things I've tried:

- Variations on the permissions of the access token: using either the max. or min. needed do not resolve the issue.
- Isolating language binding bugs: I have written test code in both Go and Node.js, and both experience the same issue.
- Using different versions of the api: both `1.0` and `2.0` demonstrate the same issue.

I'm really at my wits end here. I don't know to troubleshoot further. Any ideas?

Comment: If using only changing limit give you different amount of results that sounds like a bug. And you should file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Yep I am 99.99% sure this is a bug. I get a different number of results with just about every variation of limit. 10000 is even different from 225 (which seems to give me all of the results, even though 300 doesn't...).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears from the comments that this is a bug in Facebook's API and not something for which an answer can be provided here

Comment: Do you have a link to the FB bug report? Was it fixed? Do you happen to know a workaround for this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/57454155/470749  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily a "bug" - it is sort of documented: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/

In essence the limit is applied BEFORE filtering the results (like deleted posts or visibility) and thus the limit does not always match the number of posts you're getting. Even worse is you can get empty pages within your result set and you'll need to check for a few pages further in the empty space to be sure that nothing is left.

Posts can get pretty sparse when you're reaching back a lot of time because of deleted user accounts and such stuff. So you might get slots of 200 or something where nothing is returned because all the posts there are gone.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but please re-read my question — it seems you didn't really understand the issue. the issue is not that the API is returning incomplete results, or even that the # of results returns doesn't match the # requested. The issue is that de-paginating API calls starting with limit=20 returns a substantially different number of results — in total — as compared to limit=21, or limit=22. It's an inconsistency, and Facebook has confirmed the bug, but has yet to release a fix.

Comment: Have you tried paging further into the empty pages to see if there are still posts left? I solved this with the time based paging a while ago when I wrote a small page comparison tool for our social media people to check some stats on the managed pages. Retrieving comments on posts is similarly tricky and setting it to scan 15 pages after the seemingly last page solved most of the inconsistency too. Sometimes there have been gaps 5-6 pages that returned completely empty before returning a single comment again and then again 5-6 empty pages until a whole new block of comments appeared.